# prometheus operator target not showing

Tags: prometheus, servicemonitor

Prometheus-operator and Prometheus were installed separately using the help chart.

For convenience, serviceMonitorNamespaceSelector and PodMonitorNamespaceSelecotr were specified in the namespace where Prometheus was deployed.

I would like to create a servicemonitor and connect endpoints to collect specific metrics such as a separate solution (Gitalb, Rook-ceph).

Gitlab and Rook-ceph are installed in separate OS, and namespace is different.

However, the ServiceMonitor does not appear in the Prometheus Target.

Is there anything I missed?

```
# rook-ceph service && servicemonitor
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2021-12-02T12:11:58Z"
  labels:
    app: rook-ceph-mgr
    ceph_daemon_id: a
    rook_cluster: rook-ceph
  name: rook-ceph-mgr
  namespace: rook-ceph
  ownerReferences:
  - apiVersion: ceph.rook.io/v1
    blockOwnerDeletion: true
    controller: true
    kind: CephCluster
    name: rook-ceph
    uid: 39e4d63d-af59-4698-9d38-513bed86d7ab
  resourceVersion: "335184"
  uid: 3c3ccfe9-9c3c-482b-85a9-fc694d5c3da8
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.43.165.239
  clusterIPs:
  - 10.43.165.239
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - name: http-metrics
    port: 9283
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9283
  selector:
    app: rook-ceph-mgr
    ceph_daemon_id: a
    rook_cluster: rook-ceph
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  name:  rook-ceph-mgr
  namespace: rook-ceph
  labels:
    app: rook-ceph-mgr
    ceph_daemon_id: a
    rook_cluster: rook-ceph
    release: prometheus
spec:
  endpoints:
  - path: /metrics
    port: http-metrics
    scheme: http
    interval: 5s
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: rook-ceph-mgr
      rook_cluster: rook-ceph
      ceph_daemon_id: a
  namespaceSelector:
    matchNames:
    - rook-ceph
```

```
# prometheus install yaml
    serviceMonitorNamespaceSelector:
      matchLabels:
        name: prometheus
    serviceMonitorSelectorNilUsesHelmValues: false
    podMonitorNamespaceSelector:
      matchLabels:
        name: prometheus
```

```
root@server1:~# kubectl get servicemonitor -A
NAMESPACE    NAME                                                 AGE
prometheus   prometheus-kube-prometheus-alertmanager              39d
prometheus   prometheus-kube-prometheus-apiserver                 39d
prometheus   prometheus-kube-prometheus-coredns                   39d
prometheus   prometheus-kube-prometheus-grafana                   39d
prometheus   prometheus-kube-prometheus-kube-controller-manager   39d
prometheus   prometheus-kube-prometheus-kube-etcd                 39d
prometheus   prometheus-kube-prometheus-kube-proxy                39d
prometheus   prometheus-kube-prometheus-kube-scheduler            39d
prometheus   prometheus-kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics        39d
prometheus   prometheus-kube-prometheus-kubelet                   39d
prometheus   prometheus-kube-prometheus-node-exporter             39d
prometheus   prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus                39d
prometheus   rke2-ingress-nginx-controller                        39d
rook-ceph    rook-ceph-mgr                                        23m
```

[image]